# AMD/ATI Sun PRO Radeon HD 8570A/8570M cannot install catalyst ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ati, radeon, catalyst

I am unable to install catalyst drivers for Radeon HD 8570M graphic card. If I use new drivers from AMD site I will get an error during the installation like cannot detect suported videocard. If I use some old catalyst drivers I am able to finish installation but after reboot I have got black screen which was blicking and I am not able to start tty1 via alt + ctrl + f1. How to install my card ? please do not past any links with general installation guide.... trust me I am trying them 2 days with same results... thanks a lot

```
lspci


00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8570A/8570M] (rev ff)


uname -r
3.13.0-37-generic


lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary OS
Description:    elementary OS Freya
Release:    0.3
Codename:   freya
```